# Is there a way to access switch case from other method?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm developing a maths quiz program which will ask the user whether the wanna have Addition, Subtraction, Division or Multiplication quiz. So by using switch case statement can I access the method?

```
public static void Addition(){ 

} 

public static void Subtraction(){

} 

public static void Division(){ 

} 

Public static void Multi(){

} 

static void option(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = 0; 

        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
    choice = input.nextInt(); 

switch (choice){ 
            case 1: 
                break; 
            case 2: 
                break; 
            case 3: 
                break; 
            case 4: 
                break; 
            default: 
                                break;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can call `Division` (Or another one of your methods) within your switch statement?

Comment: @GBlodgett yes, is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Did you try it?

Comment: @GBlodgett I'm not sure about the syntax so I didn't

Comment: How do you normally call a method?

Comment: @GBlodgett Multi(); or Diversion();

Answer (score 0):

Proper syntax would be, for example:

```
switch (choice){ 
        case 1:
            Addition();
            break; 
        case 2: 
            Subtraction();
            break; 
        case 3: 
            Division();
            break; 
        case 4: 
            Multi();
            break; 
        default: 
            break;
}
```

I would recommend usually naming methods in Java with [camelcase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Answer (score 0):

I think you really want something like this:

```
public static double add(double x, double y){ 
  return x + y;
} 

public static double subtract(double x, double y){
  ...
} 

public static void divide(double x, double y){ 
  ...    
} 

public static double multiply(double x, double y){
  ...        
} 

public static void main (String[] args ) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int choice = -1;
  while (choice != 5) {
     System.out.print("1) add, 2) subtract, 3) divide, 4) multiply 5) quit");
     int choice = input.nextInt();
     // Get x, y, result
     switch (choice){ 
            case 1: 
                result = add(x, y);
                break; 
            case 2: 
                result = subtract(x, y);
                break; 
            case 3: 
                result = divide(x, y);
                break; 
            case 4: 
                result = multiply(x, y);
                break; 
            default: 
                System.out.println("Exiting program...");
                return;
           break;
      }
  }
```

Note that you should probably leverage the ability to pass a "[return value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming))" from functions (methods).  Note, too, that methods are usually "[camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming))" (e.g. "addNumbers()", instead of "Addition()".